# Broadcasting Video and show to multiple users using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, socket.io

I need some idea about video broadcasting among multiple users.

I have one video file on my app's page and when the initiator will play this video all user can see this those are visiting this same page at the same time.

When initiator will stop/pause this video it will reflect same in all user's side. Please help me to make this by providing any reference link or code.

Comment: here's something that may help https://www.youtube.com/my_live_events

Comment: @ Raptor : Yes,I know Node.js and socket.io but i need a good start.Can you provide any reference link for this so that i can start.

Comment: @ Jaromanda : It is asking to verify my google account.I want to make app.

Comment: I thought youtube live is a good reference, sorry

Comment: the simplest solution might be,  adding initator and users to a socket.io room, then emitting all of his actions(play, pause/stop) to server, which would then broadcast it to the room, and users in the room, would carry out the appropriate action

Comment: @ mido22 : I can understand but how  initiator  will show them the streaming video which is playing in his side.